# Can "why" questions be answered without using "because" or "to"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, responses

At schools in my country they teach that you should answer using the word "because" or "to" when you are asked "why".

Can't you answer without "because" or "to"?

> Why does he go home so early every day?
>
> He has to play with his dog.

Can it be natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not a rule that you must answer a *why*-question with "because" or "to".  It is perfectly natural to answer without saying "Because..." if it's clear from context.

For example,

> "Why did Mitch leave school early?"
> "He felt sick."

Comment: I would argue this is the same as using "because" as it is implied here.  "Because he felt sick."

Comment: @myacorn Sure.  I'm just addressing the point that you don't literally have to use the word "because", which the OP seems to imply is his teachers' rule.